# Group by Year and ID and then sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have table with 3 columns - ID, Year and Value.
Example of the table:

[image: table1]

Some rows from the picture:

```
id, year ,value
 1, 2017 ,19
 1, 2017 ,21
 1, 2017 ,22
 1, 2018 ,1
 1, 2018 ,30
 1, 2018 ,15
 1, 2018 ,17
 1, 2018 ,2
 1, 2018 ,18
 1, 2019 ,23
 1, 2019 ,3
 1, 2020 ,6
 1, 2020 ,9
 2, 2017 ,16
 2, 2017 ,14
 2, 2017 ,13
 2, 2017 ,12
 2, 2017 ,22
 2, 2017 ,20
 2, 2017 ,23
 2, 2017 ,1
 2, 2017 ,25
 2, 2018 ,17
 2, 2019 ,10
 2, 2019 ,5
 2, 2020 ,19
 2, 2020 ,16
 2, 2020 ,14
 3, 2020 ,2
 3, 2020 ,9
 3, 2020 ,11
```

I need to sum all the values that has the same ID and Year (for example - ID=1, Year=2020 -> sum=15)
The table attached is much smaller than the original one (the original has nearly 12000 rows) so handly check is alot of work.

There is a simple way to do that?

Comment: Look into Pivot Table.

Comment: Hey @Ram Rahamim,, its easy to with FILTER only,, in Value column in last cell apply `=Subtotal(9,Range)` & then apply proper combination of ID & Year the SUBTOTAL formula will take care of  it.

Answer (score 4):

In Excel 365, you can do this with dynamic arrays.

**Method 1 — Wide Format**

Given a table in cell `A1` named `Table1` with headers `id`, `year`, and `value`,
first bring in unique IDs by placing this formula in cell `E2`:

`=UNIQUE(Table1[id])`.

Next, pull in unique years by placing this formula in cell `F1`:

`=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(Table1[year]))`.

Finally, calculate the sums by placing this formula in cell `F2`:

`=SUMIFS(Table1[value],Table1[id],E2#,Table1[year],F1#)`.

The result looks as follows:

[image: wide format solution]

**Method 2 — Long Format**

Given a table in cell `A1` named `Table1` with headers `id`, `year`, and `value`, first bring in the unique combinations of `id` and `year` by placing this formula in cell `E2`:

`=UNIQUE(Table1[[id]:[year]])`

Next use `SUMIFS()` to find the sums in cell `G2`:

`=SUMIFS(Table1[value],Table1[id],INDEX(E2#,,1),Table1[year],INDEX(E2#,,2))`.

Here I use `INDEX(E2#,,1)` and `INDEX(E2#,,2)` to get the unique IDs and years from the filtered table.

Finally, in cell `E1` enter `=Table1[#Headers]` to copy over the headers. Your final analysis looks like this:

[image: long format solution]

**Method 3 — Pivot Table**

If you're not on Excel 365, this can also be done easily by inserting a pivot table and configuring as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing data in a usable (text) form.

I think the pivot tables from Power Query (available in Excel 2010+) look better than those generated by classic Excel (and the language is also more flexible, if you want to do other things).

With your cursor in some cell in the table:

- `Data --> Get & Transform --> from Table/Range`
- In the PQ Editor that opens, select the `Year` column

  - Transform --> Pivot

    - Select `value` for the Values column
    - Select `Sum` for the Aggregate Value Function

[image]

- `Close and Load To`

and you are done:

[image]